# CameraPosition with bounds using GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming, marker, bounds

I'm having a bit of a struggle using CameraPosition because I can't have a proper zoom.
For me, a proper zoom would be the distance between a Marker and my current position.
However, I managed to get a proper zoom using CameraUpdateFactory, but the I lost all the other attributes (orientation (looking always north) and bird-eye (45 degrees view)).

I'm balanced between this (doesn't have the right zoom):

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(current_location)
                        .zoom(mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom)
                        .bearing(location.getBearing())
                        .tilt(birdEyesAngle)
                        .build();
```

and this (right zoom, but missing other attributes):

```
CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds_between_two_markers, 10);
```

Is there any way to have both correct zoom and correct orientation/bird-eye ?

Hope you'll help,
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Get the `CameraUpdate` object first using the `newLatLngBounds` method:

```
CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds_between_two_markers, 10);
```

The following code I put in my `onMapReady()` method:

```
        LatLng pos = new LatLng(51.516667, 12.388889);
        LatLng pos1 = new LatLng(53.516667, 14.388889);

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = setUserMarker(pos);
        if(markerOptions != null) {
            markerOptions.title(campusLocationName);
            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }

        LatLngBounds.Builder b = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        b.include(pos);
        b.include(pos1);

        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(b.build(),  20);
        mMap.animateCamera(cu, 10, new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.e(TAG, "Start animate onFinish");
                CameraPosition cp = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .zoom(mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom)
                        .target(pos)
                        .tilt(45.0f)
                        .bearing(35.0f)
                        .build();
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cp));
//                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cp));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.e(TAG, "Start animate onCancel");
            }
        });
```

The result from my device:

[image]

Using the `CancelableCallBack` you can make the changes to the camera position as before, but if you do not change the zoom factor, the camera keeps the old zoom factor, you just set the `bearing` and `tilt` as you like.

Comment: For some reasons it doesn't work.
It totally ignore the zoom/target/bearing/tilt and takes only the very first "animateCamera" with bounds.

Comment: @FabriceFroehly :: Take a look at the code, again. This is the exact code I put in my `onMapReady()` method and got the result I am showing as a screenshot. Check the code. It works. :: Also check to see that the messages show in the logcat.

Comment: I used your code, then I updated it and applied my 2 LatLng, and it kinda work.
The position is correct, but, since I'm calling the fonction every second (since it's supposed to adjust while the person is driving). Because of that, the camera is rotating on every second because it "resets" the code above resets the camera position at each call.

It means that the camera gets its zoom correct, then it applies the bird-eye (45°) and rotate correctly, but then, a second later, it resets the rotation and bird to apply them once again. And again each time the fonction is being called.

Comment: @FabriceFroehly :: you only need to call the code above once. That will set the map location, zoom, tilt and bearing. If you only want to change camera positions simply get the new position `LatLng pos = new LatLng(lat, lng);` and apply it to the map with `newLatLng()` like this :: `mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(pos));`. This way all the other setting are preserved.